# How to place my g+ or fb plugin at the bottom of post or page?

Tags: widgets

I recently installed the google+ and facebook widget plugins to my pages and I do not like it's current position. I'm not sure where to begin looking..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the plugin, but you could edit your post template and either use a template tag (if one exists), a shortcode (if one exists), or [call the widget directly](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget). Either way, you'll have to edit the template (unless you want to register a new sidebar).